# Breaking down a navigation using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was asking myself if you can break down a single-line navigation into *n* rows when the window width gets below the navigation width.

**For example:**

I have 8 elements like this.

```
[1]-[2]-[3]-[4]-[5]-[6]-[7]-[8]
```

Now when the window width gets too small I want them to be seperated into two rows and when it gets too small again I want three or four rows and so on like below.

```
[1]-[2]-[3]-[4]
[5]-[6]-[7]-[8]
```

Is there a way to do this just by using Twitter Bootstraps' CSS and Classes?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/H7YNW/

Comment: BS will collapse and hide the navigation with menu button top right when screen width gets small...

Comment: But that's not what I want it to do. Read carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the appropriate Bootstrap `col=*` classes to acheive this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">5</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">6</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">7</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">8</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

For your UL list it looks like..

```
   <div class="row">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <a href="services.html">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <a href="404.html">Studies</a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <a href="404.html">References</a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <a href="404.html">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <a href="404.html">Press</a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <a href="404.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <a href="404.html">Impressum</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
  </div>
```

http://bootply.com/88121

Comment: Thanks, you absolutely nailed it!

Comment: The only problem now is the mobile-first-approach. Actually I dont want it to be in grids if it's got enough space. Aren't there appropriate tags in BS3?

Comment: So you mean you want it to maintain the 8 columns on smaller widths?

Comment: I want it to be in grid only on smaller screens.

Comment: You would need to tweak use of the col-* classes

Comment: Thanks. I guess that'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't part of the Bootstrap navigation, but maybe you can make your own custom one. Bootstrap has these classes called col-md-X. X being the number of columns you want to take up. It doesn't break it down exactly how you asked, though.

Once it hits a certain width, each div gets it's own row.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

Test it out for yourself, see if it fits your needs :)